# PDF-file thumbnails are shown in wrong color

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, typo3, thumbnails, typo3-extensions

On a page (TYPO3 Website, ext.: ImageMagick) I want to show thumbnails of available/downloadable pdf-files (always 1st page of the pdf-file as thumbnail). The problem is that the thumbnails (*.gif but I also tried *.jpg and *.png) are created in 'wrong colors', I mean they differ from the pdf content itself (Thumbnails: dark blue color is shown in light blue).

Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This causes PDF with color model CMYK. It will looks fine with ImageMagick when color model is RGB. In such case I prefer to use GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick and change the settings in Installtool or LocalConfiguration from for example

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['colorspace'] = 'sRGB';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['im_version_5'] = 'im6';
```

to

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['colorspace'] = 'RGB';
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['im_version_5'] = 'gm';
```

Comment: so you recommend in case 1 to convert the PDF into RGB? Am I right with my assumption? 
This would be nice, because I need permissions to change settings like this (case 2 / your second advice) - so I am not allowed to at the moment.

Comment: My experience was, that IM is not able to convert AI/PDF with CMYK color model to nice looking RGB colored thumbnails. GM can. You could convert your PDF to RGB or switch to GM. Convert to RGB is a temporarly solution, and is maybe not prefered of PDF's for print, and think in CMS context - new uploaded PDF's would be in CMYK again.

Comment: To convert CMYK to RGB, it is best to use color profiles. That usually does a good job and better than just using -colorspace